# How to determine if the following equation has a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$
\begin{array}{l}
l(\varphi)=\frac{f^{\prime}(\varphi)}{[a f(\varphi)+b]^{2} \tan \varphi} \\
\text { and }\left\{\begin{array}{l}
l(0)=a \\
l\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=a
\end{array}\right. \\
\text { solve } f(\varphi)
\end{array}
$
I know that solving this question might be difficult. Is there an approximation method that can be used to solve it? For example, suppose I assume that the solution is of the form ​$f=a_n\varphi^n+...+a_1\varphi+a_0$
, but I am not sure how to proceed from there. Can you suggest any techniques or strategies to help me tackle this problem?

Answer (score 3):

$$l(\varphi)=\frac{f^{\prime}(\varphi)}{[a f(\varphi)+b]^{2} \tan \varphi}$$
$$l(\varphi)\tan \varphi\:d\varphi=\frac{df}{[a f+b]^{2}}$$
$$\int_0^\varphi l(\theta)\tan \theta\:d\theta =\frac{-1}{a(a f+b)}+C$$
$$f(\varphi)=\frac{-1}{a^2 \left(\int_0^\varphi l(\theta)\tan \theta\:d\theta -C\right) } -\frac{b}{a}$$
$\begin{cases}
l(0)=a \\
l\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=a
\end{cases}$ are properties of the function $l\left(\varphi\right)$. They are not boundary condition for the ODE. Whitout boundary condition one cannot determine $C$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Given the specified boundary conditions, can this problem be solved using numerical methods?

Comment: What is the boundary condition ?